# C# : Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a set of row data as follows

```
 List<String> l_lstRowData = new List<string> { "Data 1 32:01805043*0FFFFFFF", 
                                                "Data 3, 20.0e-3", 
                                                "Data 2, 1.0e-3 172:?:CRC" ,
                                                "Data 6"
                                              };
```

and two List namely "KeyList" and "ValueList" like

```
 List<string> KeyList = new List<string>();
 List<string> ValueList = new List<string>();
```

I need to fill the two `List<String>` from the data from `l_lstRowData` using `Pattern Matching`

And here is my `Pattern` for this

```
 String l_strPattern = @"(?<KEY>(Data|data|DATA)\s[0-9]*[,]?[ ]?[0-9e.-]*)[ \t\r\n]*(?<Value>[0-9A-Za-z:?*!. \t\r\n\-]*)";
 Regex CompiledPattern=new Regex(l_strPattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

So finally the two `List`s will contain

```
 KeyList 

            { "Data 1" }
            { "Data 3, 20.0e-3" }
            { "Data 2, 1.0e-3" }
            { "Data 6" }



 ValueList 

            { "32:01805043*0FFFFFFF" }
            { "" }
            { "172:?:CRC" }
            { "" }
```

Scenerio:

The `Group` `KEY` in the Pattern Should match "The `data` followed by an integer value , and the if there exist a comma(,) then the next string i.e a  `double` value

The `Group` `Value` in the Pattern should match string after the `whitespace`.In the first string it should match `32:01805043*0FFFFFFF` but in the 3rd `172:?:CRC`.

Here is my sample code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < l_lstRowData.Count; i++)
        {
            MatchCollection M = CompiledPattern.Matches(l_lstRowData[i], 0);
            KeyList.Add(M[0].Groups["KEY"].Value);
            ValueList.Add(M[0].Groups["Value"].Value);

        }
```

But my `Pattern` is not working in this situation.

**EDIT**

My code result like

```
 KeyList 

            { "Data 1 32" } // 32 should be in the next list
            { "Data 3, 20.0e-3" }
            { "Data 2, 1.0e-3" }
            { "Data 6" }



 ValueList 

            { ":01805043*0FFFFFFF" }
            { "" }
            { "172:?:CRC" }
            { "" }
```

Please help me to rewrite my Pattern.

Comment: I would run the match against the failing cases and break it down part by part. (E.g. determine what "is not working" means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simpler regex would work:  `(?<key>data \d(?:, [\d.e-]+)?)(?<value>.*)` will match your keys and values, providing you use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag too.

You can see the results at this [Rubular example link](http://rubular.com/r/EPdTM3Zfse).

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me, so please define what's not working.

Also:

- start your regexp with ^ and end it with $
- use regex.Match() instead of Matches() because you know it'll only match once
- i don't see why you use IgnorePatternWhitespace
- use a simple comma instead of [,], a simple space instead of [ ]
- use \s instead of [ \t\r\n]
- if you specify IgnoreCase, then no need for Data|data|DATA or [A-Za-z]

And if you clean this up, maybe you can solve it alone :)

Comment: Took me a bit to find "the problem". In the result, ":01805043*0FFFFFFF" should be lead with 32 (e.g.) "32:01805043*0FFFFFFF"

Comment: Agree with everything in the post above. Also, to simplify your tests, it should be wise tu use a tool like Rad regular expression designer or something.